# Getting error when establishing connection between dockers (One is Rest service and second is Rest client)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Unable to establish connections between docker using docker-compose.yml

I am new to the docker world so apologies beforehand if my questions are not clear. So what I am trying to do is have two dockers one of which is rest service and the second one is the rest client. I am trying to establish the network connection between the two

Path of the docker rest service /Users/gsha/learning/producer Details about my rest service

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ProducerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProducerApplication.class, args);
    }
}



server.port=8085
server.servlet.context-path=/producer-service

Path of this Dockerfile /Users/gsha/learning/producer
```

**Rest Client Info
Path /Users/gsha/learning/consumer**

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ConsumerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConsumerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
   

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@RestController
public class SimpleRestConsumer {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String getHello(){
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String val = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8085/producer-service", String.class);
        return val;
    }

}

server.port=8086
server.servlet.context-path=/consumer-service
address.service.base-path=http://localhost:8085/producer-service
```

**Path to the yaml file :/Users/gsha/learning/docker-compose.yml
(I am confused if this is the right path to place the yaml file)
(Can somebody help me how should I write this yaml file...bit confused)**

```
version: "3"

services:
  producer-service:
    build:
      context: ../producer-service
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8085:8085

  consumer-service:
    build:
      context: ../consumer-service
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8086:8086
    depends_on:
      - producer-service

Getting this error when doing the deployment

docker-compose up --build
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)
unable to prepare context: path "../producer-service" not found
```

Comment: `../producer-service` seems to be one directory higher than your `docker-compose.yml` . You should put `docker-compose.yml` at the highest directory. Please share your directory structure.

Comment: @sudipto : docker-compose.yml : Path : /Users/gsha/learning                   
 producer-service Path /Users/gsha/learning/producer                              
 consumer-service Path /Users/gsha/learning/consumer

Comment: where is other `Dockerfile`s with respect to `docker-compose.yml`. Could you please share ?

Comment: It seems that your build context is not pointing to the right directory `context: ../producer-service`

Comment: @Sudipto : The path of my first docker file (the Producer) is /Users/gsha/learning/producer and the second docker file (the consumer) is /Users/gsha/learning/consumer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your directory looks like this

```
├── learning
   │  ├── producer
   │  |    └── Dockerfile # Dockerfile for Producer
   │  ├── consumer 
   │  |     └── Dockerfile # Consumer Dockerfile
   │  └── docker-compose.yml
   └── …
```

It seems that your build context path is not right. Try this

```
version: "3"

services:
  producer-service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./producer/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8085:8085

  consumer-service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile:  ./consumer/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8086:8086
    depends_on:
      - producer-service
```

Add correct path to the Dockerfile for producer and consumer service. I added an example path according to my assumption that the `Dockerfile` exist in  `./producer/Dockerfile` and `./consumer/Dockerfile`

Comment: Thanks that really solved the path issue. Although I am getting this error now.

Comment: => ERROR [learning_consumer-service 3/5] COPY target/dependency/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib                                                                                                                0.0s
 => ERROR [learning_consumer-service 4/5] COPY target/dependency/META-INF /app/META-INF                                                                                                               0.0s
 => ERROR [learning_consumer-service 5/5] COPY target/dependency/BOOT-INF/classes /app

Comment: your `docker-compose` is now OK, I have to see your `Dockerfiles` , Maybe its failing to copy some library

Comment: FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring
USER spring:spring
ARG DEPENDENCY=target/dependency
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","hello.Application"]

Comment: It is from this spring boot guide https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/

Comment: Seems that the path to the `DEPENDENCY` is not right. look at this line in the  docker compose `context: .`  This simply means that you are defining the directory which contains `docker-compose.yml` as a root directory. So if you wat to copy anything you have to provide a path relative to the `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: where is that `target/dependency` folder located?

Comment: Bit confused. can you elaborate more on that?

Comment: It is located inside learning/producer and learning/consumer

Comment: ok I am doing some edit in the dokcer compose and then see what happens

Comment: please edit your docker file and replace the `ARG DEPENDENCY=target/dependency ` with `ARG DEPENDENCY=./producer/target/dependency` and for consumer `ARG DEPENDENCY=./consumer/target/dependency`

Comment: check the `producer/target/dependency/BOOT-INF/lib` folder and ensure that you have everything  required to run entry point command. more simply do you have `hello.Application` class in that directory?

Comment: Yup. I figured it out. You were of great help today Sudipto. Thanks a ton !!

Comment: Thanks never stop learning, I remember those days when I was learning and experimenting with these things myself. That's why I do not step back ever when anyone needs help. Please accept the answer if it has helped you.

Comment: Added a positive feedback :)